# Only one Active class and Visible Div at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, show-hide

There are a bunch of `div` elements on the page.

I have a nested `div` inside of them.

I want to be able to add a class to the `click`ed element, and `.show()` the child div.

```
$('.container').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red').children('.insideItem').slideToggle();
});
```

- I can click on it, it drops down.
- Click again, it goes away.

So, now I need some method to `removeClass()` and `slideUp()` *all* of the other ones in the event of a click *anywhere except the open div*. Naturally, I tried something like this:

```
$('html').on('click', function(){
    $('.container').removeClass('red').children('div').slideUp();
});
```

Well, that just stops the effect from staying in the first place. I've read around on `event.Propagation()` but I've read that should be avoided if possible.

I'm trying to avoid using any more prebuilt plugins like `accordion`, as this should be a pretty straightforward thing to accomplish and I'd like to know a simple way to make it work.

Would anyone be able to show a quick example on this fiddle how to resolve this?

- Show only one active div, and collapse all others if clicked off

https://jsfiddle.net/4x1Lsryp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it is to update your code with the following:

1) prevent the click on a square from bubbling up to the parent elements
2) make sure to reset the status of all the squares when a new click is made anywhere.

```
$('.container').on('click', function(){
  $this = $(this);
  $('.container').not($this).removeClass('red').children('div').slideUp();
  $this.toggleClass('red').children('div').slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

See the updated JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pdL0y0xz/

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine your two approaches:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('#wrap').append("<div class='container'>" + i + "<div class='insideDiv'>Inside Stuff</div></div>");
}

$('.container').on('click', function() {
  var hadClassRed = $(this).hasClass('red');
  $('.container').removeClass('red').children('div').slideUp();
  if (!hadClassRed) {
    $(this).toggleClass('red').children('div').slideToggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
  margin: 1em;
}
.insideDiv {
  display: none;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap"></div>
```